# Eclipse BPMN2 Modeller - linking from one BPMN file to another?

Tags: eclipse, bpmn

I'm working on a project that uses an extremely complex BPMN file, so I've been tasked with seeing if splitting it into multiple BPMNs can be done i.e. have it go from one BPMN file into another. We are using Eclipse's BPMN2 Modeler, are there any ways of doing this outside of implementing a Sub-Process? And is there a way for it to happen as a user carries out tasks rather than right at the start, for instance when the user reaches a certain point in the sequence it jumps to another BPMN, otherwise it does not?

Answer (score 1):

You could use message events to signal to different lanes/flows of your original BPMN.

This would enable you to split the flow into sub-BPMN diagrams which can accept message events to start the sub-flow, and emit message events when they're complete to continue the wider process.

Answer (score 0):

Subprocesses is the best way to split chunks of processes into separate units. Based on your question: "for instance when the user reaches a certain point in the sequence it jumps to another BPMN" that is when you place a sub process activity.
I wonder why you are discarding that approach.